# str_to_hive function splits each character of the string as key

Tags: string, dictionary, hive

I have a string `"description=Qiemo|locationToolsID=733"` in one of the string column in hive. When I try to convert this to map using the delimiter `|` for each KV and `=` for key and value, it doesn't work.

Specifically, when I run:

```
str_to_map(str('description=Qiemo|locationToolsID=733'),'|','=').
```

I was expecting

```
description:Qiemo
locationToolsID:733
```

but I am getting like this

```
{"a":null,"":"","c":null,"d":null,"D":null,"e":null,"i":null,"I":null,"l":null,"m":null,"n":null,"o":null,"p":null,"Q":null,"r":null,"s":null,"3":null,"t":null,"T":null,"7":null,"|":null}
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the `|` character as it has special meaning in Java regular expression.
You can try this:

```
select str_to_map("description=Qiemo|locationToolsID=733",'\\\|','=');
                         OR
select str_to_map("description=Qiemo|locationToolsID=733",'[|]','=');
```

Output would be: `{"locationToolsID":"733","description":"Qiemo"}`